# Hi, I need a SQL query each cell in a column must contain a least one alpha character (A-Z, a-z)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a a SQL query where each cell in a column must contain a least one alpha character (A-Z, a-z).

I have tried different combinations of ISNUMERIC, LIKE & ISALPHABET & also searched google but cant work it out.  IS Alphanumeric also does not work for this situation.

The input in the column is :

```
3
3-5
3 RYDE ST
RYDE ST
```

I want the output to be Row 1 & 2 as below, because these do not include an alpha character.  I will then manually alter the cells to ensure they meet the condition to have at least one alpha character:

```
3
3-5
```

Comment: Read about Patindex.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name
LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%'`

The `%` matches anything. So you are looking for anything followed by a letter followed by anything.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately this did not work, I have tried it.  It does not return anything.  I have checked my input data is fine cause this following SQL works 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column NOT LIKE '[^0-9]'  However this returned where field alphanumberic.  3-5, 3 Ryde St & Ryde St.  It does not return where just a mumber.